# Why is the plugin not executing

Tags: jquery, html, plugins

I have a basic slider that I created: https://jsfiddle.net/n68pgfvs/

What I am looking to do is, instead of making it static to just a class, I wanted to convert it into a plugin so I can use it multiple times at the same page.

I was looking through this page to create a simple one to begin with: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

So I came up with the following (as a test):

```
<div>
    <div class="test1">This is a test</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(".test1").SliderS({
        color: "#00FF00"
    });
</script>
<script>
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.SliderS = function (options) {
            var settings = $.extend({
                autoSlide: 1,
                timeoutSet: 4000,
                displayNav: 1,
                color: "#F00FFF"
            }, options);

            return this.css({ color: settings.color });
        };
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Based on the tutorial it should change the text color but it didn't.

How can I resolve it?

Also, what is the best way to convert my static codes from my slider into a plugin to be used many times?

Comment: monitor your console errors. *"SliderS is not a function"* error should have been a big clue

Comment: Didn't get any error but it's fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your plugin before you define it. Switch the order and it works fine:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.SliderS = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      autoSlide: 1,
      timeoutSet: 4000,
      displayNav: 1,
      color: "#F00FFF"
    }, options);

    return this.css({
      color: settings.color
    });
  };
}(jQuery));

$(".test1").SliderS({
  color: "#00FF00"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="test1">This is a test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Any recommendation how I should proceed with my slider code?

Comment: That question is a little too broad for StackOverfow. You need to attempt to convert it to a plugin yourself and then come back if you have a specific question about your implementation.